# How to automatically :load script in Scala shell?

Tags: scala

Is there a way to launch the Scala shell and automatically execute the `:load` command to process a script?

Conversely, to execute a Scala script, but on completion land in Scala shell (instead of exiting) would work equally well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
scala -i Script.scala
```

is what you want.